# Transparent background not working with GIF(Tkinter)

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, animated-gif

I seem to be having some problems getting the background of a gif to become transparent. I have attached the code below :

```
class MyLabel(Label):
    def __init__(self, master, filename, delayms):
        im = Image.open(filename)
        seq =  []
        self.delay = 10
        try:
            while 1:
                seq.append(im.copy())
                im.seek(len(seq)) # skip to next frame
        except EOFError:
            pass # we're done

        try:
            self.delay =  delayms#im.info['duration']
        except KeyError:
            self.delay = 10

        first = seq[0].convert('RGBA')
        self.frames = [ImageTk.PhotoImage(first)]
        canvas = Canvas(master, bg="red", width=500, height=400)
        canvas.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.5, anchor='center')
        Label.__init__(self, canvas, image=self.frames[0])

        temp = seq[0]
        for image in seq[1:]:
            temp.paste(image)
            frame = image.convert('RGBA')
            self.frames.append(ImageTk.PhotoImage(frame))

        self.idx = 0

        self.cancel = self.after(self.delay, self.play)

    def play(self):
        self.config(image=self.frames[self.idx])
        self.idx += 1
        if self.idx == len(self.frames):
            self.idx = 0
        self.cancel = self.after(self.delay, self.play)
```

I have done some research and tried different solutions, however nothing seems to be working for me.

Comment: Please define "some problems" - you haven't posted a [mcve], so we have no way of seeing the problem for ourselves.

Comment: @jasonharper The gif will load into the frame, however the background is white.

Comment: What were you expecting it to be?  The Label containing the image is opaque, as are all Tkinter widgets, so its background color is the only thing you can hope to see through transparent areas of the image.

Comment: @jasonharper the transparent areas of the GIF aren't working. They're just coming up as white.

Comment: Have you tried adding the image directly to the canvas, instead of putting it on a label on the canvas?

Comment: @BryanOakley I have not, However I seem to having issues setting that up.

Comment: The Tcl/Tk Label does not support the transparent background. Add the image to the canvas with ```Canvas.create_image()``` as Bryan said.